# finite division algebras over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

A theorem of Wedderburn says that finite division ring is field.

Here, ring means "ring with unity and is also associative".

In particular, finite division (associative) algebras are fields.

I was trying to get examples of following kind of algebras.

> **Q 1.** What are the examples of finite division non-associative algebras over a field of order $p$, a prime?
>
> **Q.2** Where can I find the properties of algebras in Q. 1?

---

Note that there are simple examples of finite non-associative algebras, namely Lie algebras over a finite field of finite dimension; but they are not necessarily (perhaps never) division algebras.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614634/division-rings-and-division-algebras

Comment: Have you looked at Glynn's _On finite division algebras_?

Comment: @pregunton: the link you stated contains *associative* division rings, whereas my question is about *non-associative* only.